# Change for all true answers on test with $25$ questions

Tags: probability

I'm curious. Imagine we have a test with $25$ questions and each question have $4$ possible answers but only one of them is true. What is the percentage of guessing all questions right? How to calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility of answering one question correct is $1$ in $4$.

The possibility of answering two questions correct is $0.25 \times 0.25=0.0625$ or $1$ in $16$ or $1$ in $4^2$.

The possibility of answering three questions correct is $0.25 \times 0.25 \times 0.25$ or $1$ in $4^3$.

The possibility of answering four questions correct is $0.25 \times 0.25 \times 0.25 \times 0.25$ or $1$ in $4^4$.

...

The possibility of answering $25$ questions correct is $1$ in $4^{25}$. Divide $1$ by $4^{25}$ then multiply by $100$, we will have the percentage of answering all questions right.

The multiplication is because the possibility of answering each question is independent from the others.

Answer (score 1):

Since the single probability to guess one answer is $\frac14$, we simply have for the [rule of product](https://brilliant.org/wiki/probability-rule-of-product/) for probability

$$P=\left(\frac14\right)^{25}=\frac1{4^{25}}\approx 8.882×10^{-14}\,\%$$

More interesting would be the probability to guess at least $13$ answers and pass the test which can be calculated by the sum of the probabilities to have exactly $13,14,15,...25$ answers correct that is

$$\sum_{k=13}^{25}\left[\binom{25}{k}\left(\frac14\right)^k \left(\frac34\right)^{25-k}\right]\approx 0.091583144 \%$$

Answer (score 1):

Every answer has a $\frac{1}{4}$ chance to be correct. For $25$ questions, that would be $(\frac{1}{4})^{25} = 8.882×10^{-14}%$. In short, the probability is pretty small.